# Import React ,{Component} from ‘react’

Tags: reactjs

When executing:

`create-react-app 3.2.0`

I got the following warning:

> Compiled with warnings.
>
> ./src/App.js
>   Line 1:16:  'Component' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
>   To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
>
> create-react-app 3.2.0 does not support `import React,{Component} from 'react';`

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

This just means you never actually used the Component class in your code.

If youre using functional components you can remove the {Component} import and your code should work just fine

Comment: 添加了// eslint-disable-next-line之后控制台不会发出警告

Comment: Unfortunatelly I dont understand chinese bro, can you write that in english?

Comment: I wrote "// eslint-disable-next-line" on the first line. The console does not issue a warning or "Component" is called in my class.

Comment: `// eslint-disable-next-line` is used to disable all ESLint rules for the next line.